# Question on finding group isomorphic to $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group with generators $a$ and $b$ given by $G = \langle a,b:a^4 = b^2 = e, ba = a^{-1}b\rangle$

Let $Z(G)$ denote the centre of the group.

Then I need to show that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is isomorphic to the Klein's four group $K_4$.his

This is a question from my textbook.

I have confusion in this question.

It's no where written that order of $a$ and $b$ are $4$ and $2$ respectively.

If I take both $a$ and $b$ to be identity then $G$ is a trivial group.

If I take just $a$ to be identity, then $G$ is of order $2$.

Then how can the result be true?

Comment: That is not a correct argument. $a^4=1$ does not imply that the order of $a$ is 4. It can be $2$  or $1$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

It seems your confusion is less about the computation and more about what "$G = \langle a,b \mid a^4 = b^2 = e, ba = a^{-1}b\rangle$" means, so let me clarify that point for you.

When a group is given by a [presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) like $G = \langle a,b \mid a^4 = b^2 = e, ba = a^{-1}b\rangle,$ this means something very specific. Formally, $G$ is the quotient of the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) $F_2$ on two [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) $a$ and $b$ by the relations $a^4 = b^2 = e,$ and $abab^{-1} = e.$ That is, let $N$ be the normal closure of the subgroup of $F_2$ generated by $a^4,$ $b^2,$ and $abab^{-1}.$ Then $G$ is defined to be the quotient group $F_2/N.$

In plainer language, writing $G = \langle a,b \mid a^4 = b^2 = e, ba = a^{-1}b\rangle$ means that all elements of $G$ are "words" in $a$ and $b$ (i.e., concatenations $a^{n_1} b^{n_2}\cdots a^{n_{r-1}} b^{n_r},$ where $r\geq 0$ and the $n_i$ are integers), and that you can simplify words as specified by the relations. For example,
\begin{align*}
a^5b^{-2}a^3b^4ab^{11} &= a^4 a (b^2)^{-1} a^3 (b^2)^2 a (b^{2})^5b\\
&= eae^{-1} a^3 e^2 a e^5 b\\
&= a^4 ab\\
&= ab.
\end{align*}

In essence, $G$ is the "free-est" or "largest" group where these relations are satisfied. This is made precise by the following universal property of $G$:

> Let $G = \langle a,b \mid a^4 = b^2 = e, ba = a^{-1}b\rangle.$ Let $H$ be a group such that there exist $\alpha,\beta\in H$ such that $\alpha^4 = \beta^2 = e,$ $\beta\alpha = \alpha^{-1}\beta,$ and that any $h\in H$ can be written as a word in $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ Then there exists a unique group homomorphism $f : G\to H$ such that $f(a) = \alpha$ and $f(b) = \beta.$ Moreover, $f$ is a surjection.

This follows from the definition of $G$ as a quotient of the free group on $a$ and $b$ and the universal property of quotient groups. The fact that $f$ is a surjection follows from the fact that any element of $H$ can be written as a word in $\alpha$ and $\beta,$ and that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in the image of $f.$

Here's the key point: **the presentation given uniquely specifies the group $G$ -- you are not working with an arbitrary group $G$ such that those relations are true**. So, you may not simply assume that the order of $a$ is $1,2,$ or $4,$ and the the order of $b$ is $1$ or $2.$ The order of $a$ and $b$ are what they are, and are determined uniquely by the presentation.

To do the problem, you can find a description of $G$ and explicitly compute $Z(G)$ and find the quotient. The group $G$ is rather small, so the computation is quite manageable.

If you're not sure how to proceed with this computation, here's a starting point: notice that the relation $ba = a^{-1}b$ lets you move $a$'s and $b$'s past each other in a word, at the cost of an $a^{-1}.$ This lets you write any word in the form $a^n b^m,$ where $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}.$ Now, try to find a set $S\subseteq\Bbb{Z}^2$ such that every element of $G$ can be written uniquely as $a^n b^m$ with $(n,m)\in S.$

Let me just end with a word about the [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups). The word problem is loosely the following: given a presentation of a group as a set of generators and relations $G = \langle S\mid R\rangle,$ how can we determine if $G$ is the trivial group? This is a very difficult problem (in fact, unsolvable in some generality), and has spawned a lot of research in group theory!

Comment: You wrote: "That is to say, when we write $a^4=b^2=e$ in the presentation of $G$, we are not saying simply that $G$ is a group satisfying these relations, but that 4 and 2 are precisely the orders of $a$ and $b$ respectively. That is very misleading. In this example it is true that $a$ and $b$ have orders $4$ and $2$, but in general a relation $a^n=e$ does not imply that $a$ ha order $n$, only that it has order dividing $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt you're right, I was being a little too careless in what I said because it is true in this situation (I also started writing up the answer and had forgotten about the other relation). I'll edit this to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to "reverse engineer" both the solution and the group $G$ given JCAA's comment (that $o(a)$  divides $4$ and $o(b)$ divides $2$) and the assumption that the question is correct. This allows us to bypass the rather subtle theory of presentations.

1. The relation $ba=a^{-1}b$ means that every element of the group can be written in the form $a^nb^m$. As $o(a)$  divides $4$ and $o(b)$ divides $2$, this means that $|G|$ divides $8$.
2. As $|G/Z(G)|=4$, we have that $4$ divides $|G|$. Hence, $|G|\in\{4, 8\}$.
3. If $|G|=4$ then $G$ is abelian, and so $G/Z(G)$ is trivial. Hence, $|G|=8$.

We can now reconstruct $G$: The fact that $|G|=8$ means that $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=1$, while $\langle a\rangle$ is normal in $G$ (it has index two, or alternatively apply the relator $ba=a^{-1}b$). Hence, $G\cong\mathbb{Z_4\rtimes Z_2}$.

We can also see how the exercise was meant to go:

1. As with (1) above, $|G|$ divides $8$.
2. Spot that $\mathbb{Z_4\rtimes Z_2}$ satisfies the relations, and so in fact $G\cong\mathbb{Z_4\rtimes Z_2}$.
3. As $G$ is non-abelian, $G/Z(G)$ is non-cyclic (this is a standard exercise).
4. Hence, either $Z(G)$ is trivial or $G/Z(G)$ is the Klein $4$-group.
5. Conclude that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial (which I shall leave to you :-) ), and so $G/Z(G)$ is the Klein $4$-group.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $$G/Z(G)\cong \operatorname{Inn}(G),$$ where $ \operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is the group of [inner automorphisms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism) of $G$.

Reference: *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition),"* by Gallian, page 194, Theorem 9.4.